# plotting lines in ggplot I get x-axis length errors

Tags: r, ggplot2, signal-processing, facet

I'm not able to plot7 time series one on top of the other using ggplot. Why does this reproducible code not work? *signal* is a factor variable with 7 values spanning 700 values (100 values each), yet somehow the values will only plot if I change the *x* in aes() to be 1:700. I'd like each signal to plot from 1 to 100. Why isn't that happening?[image]

```
signal_to_noise_ratio = 10
t=seq(0.1,10,0.1)

df <- data.frame(truesignal = sin(t))
df2 <- df

for (i in seq(5)) {
  noise = rnorm(t)
  k <- sqrt(var(t)/(signal_to_noise_ratio*var(noise)))
  data_wNoise = t + k*noise
  df2[,i] = sin(data_wNoise)
}
df[,2:6] = df2
df[,2:7] = rowSums(df2)

colnames(df) <- c("truesignal", "noisy1", "noisy2", "noisy3", "noisy4", "noisy5",
                  "stacked")
melt_df <- melt(df,measure.vars = 1:7, variable.name=c("signal"))

ggplot(data=melt_df,
       aes(x=t,y=value,colour=factor(signal))) +
  geom_path() +
  facet_grid(signal~.)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like an id variable.

```
melt_df$t.2 <- rep(1:100, 7)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=melt_df,
       aes(x=t.2, y=value, colour=factor(signal))) +
  geom_path() +
  facet_grid(signal~.)
```

Yields:

[image]

Comment: I really thought it was implicit but I guess I have to spell it out for ggplot. Thx.

Comment: Apparently. You could also do `df$t.2 <- as.integer(rownames(df))`; perhaps that's more intuitive.